# how to get file name and file count from asset folder in Android?

Tags: android, android-assets

I have some media file in my asset folder.
    I want to get all media files names and files count from my asset folder.

Answer (score 9):

A little googling might have helped you!

try this:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
String[] files = assetManager.list("your_folder_name_inside_assets");            
List<String> it = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(files));
```

Comment: There is a way to get the folder names that are in the assets folder?

Comment: Using an empty string it is possible to get the name of the folders in "assets" (but take a care; because it adds 3 additional folders: images, sounds and webkit).