# How to update activity_main.xml with file names and results

Tags: android

I am new to android development. My problem is simple. I have got some test_cases files in a folder. I want to read them ,perform some test operations on them and want show the names of files with test results on screen .But i don't know how to do that.Any suggestion will be helpful....

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530921/list-all-the-files-from-all-the-folder-in-a-single-list) is for case if you have files in folders and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22861480/how-to-get-file-name-and-file-count-from-asset-folder-in-android) is for the case if you have files in asset folder.

Comment: Yeh that will help me with File names only but i want to update their corresponding result also with them in a list format

Comment: what do you mean by "updating corresponding result"? Do you need to change somewhere in their contents?

Comment: After testing operating i get let's say true or false. so i want to update their corresponding results according to their arrangement in list